# MvvmCross Exception During Inflate

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Can anyone please help me to address below issue.

I'm trying to update Activity theme from fragment using below code in MvvmCross.

**Code**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view=null;
            if(FragmentId==Resource.Layout.my_form)
            {
                Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(Activity, Resource.Style.MyTheme_IntakeForm);

                // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
                LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.CloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

                view=localInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_form, container, false);

            }
```

**Exception**

```
Could not activate JNI Handle 0xbfa862c8 (key_handle 0x58f5101) of Java type 'mvvmcross/binding/droid/views/MvxSpinner' as managed type 'MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxSpinner'.
```

**Inner Exception**

```
        {MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: bindingContext is null during MvxAdapter creation - Adapter's should only be created when a specific binding context has been placed on the stack
      at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter..ctor (Android.Content.Context context, MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext) [0x00032] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\Views\MvxAdapter.cs:54 
      at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter..ctor (Android.Content.Context context) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\Views\MvxAdapter.cs:44 
      at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxSpinner..ctor (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\Views\MvxSpinner.cs:23 
      at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.5e8d0b16-077f-459f-9215-45a9d71443b1(intptr,object[])
      at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x000df] in <ff199c98c3f84852925dd37a0ef6113a>:0 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419789/mvvmcross-platform-exceptions-mvxexception-bindingcontext-is-null-during-mvxadap) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ensure that your binding context is not null. Try adding this line:

```
this.EnsureBindingContextIsSet(inflater);
```